# Agregar una nueva clave y valor a un array de objetos php

Tags: php, array, objeto

Tengo el siguiente array de objetos (Es la respuesta de una API):

```
$arr = [
{
    "id": 116,
    "name": "Agroservicio San José"
},
{
    "id": 347,
    "name": "Agropecuaria El Campo"
},
{
    "id": 144,
    "name": "Agroservicio Yaremi"
}];
```

Necesito agregarle a cada objeto un nuevo campo, quedando cada objeto, así:

```
{
   "id": 116,
   "name": "Agroservicio San José",
   "clave": "Valor"
}
```

He intentado lo siguiente:

```
foreach ($arr as &$val) {

        $val['campo'] = "Valor";

    }
```

Pero no me agrega el campo nuevo, he leido documentacion y mi solucion parece correcta, pero no lo hace :( tambien ya intente  $val->campo= "Valor"; y nada

Comment: ¿De dónde viene `$arr`? Esa estructura no es válida en PHP. Pregunto por si lo generas de la BD, o de una API, etc. Pon un Ejemplo Mínimo y Verificable con contenido válido en el lenguaje.

Comment: Muestra el código con que lo generas pulsando en [edit]. En ese mismo código puedes ir poniendo la nueva clave que necesitas, en vez de volver a manipular tu resultado. Aparte de que, como te dije antes, `$arr` tal y como lo presentas en la pregunta, no es ninguna estructura válida en PHP.

Comment: Viene siendo un response de una API (y la data se jala de una tabla), es por eso que no puedo poner el codigo de como se genera.

Comment: si obtienes esos datos desde una api, lo mas probable es que sea una cadena, no un array (otra cosa es que esa cadena represente un array, normalmente una cadena json). Si es tu caso, primero debes "convertirlo" en un array de php (revisa json_decode en la documentacion de php). luego, cuando sea un array valido prueba tu solución.

Comment: Si el array que llega de la api se llama `$arr`, dejanos ver que te muestra `var_dump($arr); die();`